# How do you transfer Google Music from one account to another?

Tags: google-account, google-play-music

I spent days, maybe even weeks, uploading my music to Google Music, and now that it's available for Google Apps users, I'd love to be able to transfer it to my primary google account instead of spending/wasting time doing it again. Is this possible?

Comment: I expect that will be nigh impossible. Imagine the piracy implications if you uploaded 20,000 tracks to your locker, then were able to simply transfer that locker to all and sundry.

Comment: I agree there are some piracy concerns, but I would be willing to agree to have the songs deleted from the first account after transfer, and even to jump through a couple of hoops. Sadly this is only a problem because of Google's years of treating Apps customers like the proverbial "red-headed step child". Perhaps I should just bite the bullet and re-upload.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say so, but what you are asking for is clearly not possible. It is a great privacy, piracy breach and not only Google but all the companies that I know of, do not allow transfer of any kind of digital data from one account to another.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't and I don't think Google has any plans to implement this anytime soon.

As of January 2013

> **Data Move**
>
> You can move information from one account to another for the following
>   products.
>
> - AdWords
> - Blogger
> - Bookmarks (Export and import)
> - Contacts (Export and    import)
> - FeedBurner
> - Finance: Export and Import
> - iGoogle (To transfer    data, create your own backup and restore it to the new account    through XML)
> - Picasa Web Albums
> - Places (bulk upload)
> - Reader
> - YouTube
>
> **For any other product, transferring product information is currently unavailable.** This may change over time, so check back here for
>   updates. You may find that sharing options listed below may be helpful
>   as well.

See reference: [Moving product data](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58582)